# Chrome extension only sends nativeMessage when port is disconnected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I followed Chrome's documentation on nativeMessage ([Native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/nativeMessaging/)) and implemented a simple extension which includes this:

```js
const port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.the.app');
port.postMessage('FIRST MESSAGE');
port.postMessage('Second Message');
```

I also made a binary which receives stdin and writes it in **logs.txt** file, and I know it works fine because I can test it like so:

```bash
./the_binary <<< 'test' # logs.txt now includes 'test'
```

---

Now when I enable the chrome extension, nothing happens and logs.txt is empty. Means no message is sent.

As soon as I disable the extension, the message is sent and logs.txt gets written in. Same thing happens if I press the refresh button on the extension, which basically disconnects the port and run the extension code again.

---

*My binary doesn't do any stdout at all. I know that would mess up the process and I only can stream into stderr.*

Comment: Your app probably incorrectly reads stdin, see [nativeMessaging protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/nativeMessaging/#native-messaging-host-protocol).

Comment: I think it's a bug in your native application so you should post it.